# Who should implement the TransactionManager and UserTransaction interface?

Tags: java

I've been reading the JTA JSR for a few time, but I still can't get who exactly should provide the implementation of UserTransaction and TransactionManager interfaces? What the JTA specification says is:

> The javax.transaction.UserTransaction interface provides the
>   application the ability to control transaction boundaries
>   programmatically.

and

> The javax.transaction.TransactionManager interface allows the
>   application server to control transaction boundaries on behalf of the
>   application being managed.

I suspect these implementations provide by the application server, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the application server provides the implementation of these objects. An application cannot access `TransactionManager` directly (only `TransactionSynchronizationRegistry`), but `UserTransaction` can be injected via `@Resource` or with the `java:comp/UserTransaction` JNDI lookup string.

Comment: So, a jta implementation itself doesn't provide it, right?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer since an application server includes a JTA implementation, so there's no meaningful difference for an application between "a JTA implementation" and the application server itself. I suppose an application server could include a third-party JTA implementation, which could provide the implementation, yes.